# Sorting algorithm - swaps and comparisons counter

Tags: python-3.x, quicksort, mergesort, insertion-sort

My task is to find numbers of comparisons and swaps in algorithms. I have tried several ways from the Internet, but I'm not sure it's correct. It would be great if someone just change the place of my variables (or not if everything is correct). Additional explanation is not necessary because code will be self explanatory.

```
 def insertionSort(array):
    numberOfComp = 0
    numberOfSwap = 0
    for index in range(1,len(array)):
        curr = array[index]
        position = index
        numberOfComp += 1
        while position > 0 and array[position-1] > curr:

            array[position] = array[position-1]
            position = position - 1
            numberOfSwap += 1
            numberOfComp += 1
        array[position] = curr

    complexityOfInsertion.append(numberOfComp)
    swapsOfInsertion.append(numberOfSwap)
    return array



def quickSort(array):
    global numberOfCompQuick
    global numberOfSwapsQuick

    less = []
    equal = []
    greater = []

    if len(array) > 1:
        pivot = array[int(len(array)/2)]

        for x in array:
            if x < pivot:
                less.append(x)
            if x == pivot:
                equal.append(x)
            if x > pivot:
                greater.append(x)
            numberOfCompQuick += 1
        numberOfSwapsQuick +=1
        # Don't forget to return something!
        return quickSort(less)+equal+quickSort(greater)  #the + operator to join lists

    else:  #when only have one element in array, just return the array.
        return array



def merge(a,b):
    """ Function to merge two arrays """
    global numberOfCompMerge
    global numberOfSwapsMerge
    c = []
    while len(a) != 0 and len(b) != 0:
        numberOfCompMerge += 1
        if a[0] < b[0]:
            c.append(a[0])
            a.remove(a[0])

        else:
            c.append(b[0])
            b.remove(b[0])
            numberOfSwapsMerge += 1
    if len(a) == 0:
        c += b
        numberOfSwapsMerge += 1
    else:
        numberOfSwapsMerge += 1
        c += a
    return c

# Code for merge sort

def mergeSort(array):
    """ Function to sort an array using merge sort algorithm """
    #global numberOfCompMerge
    if len(array) == 0 or len(array) == 1:
        return array
    else:
        middle = int(len(array)/2)
        a = mergeSort(array[:middle])
        b = mergeSort(array[middle:])
        return merge(a,b)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def insertionSort(array):
    numberOfComp = 0
    numberOfSwap = 0
    for index in range(1,len(array)):
        curr = array[index]
        position = index
        if position > 0: numberOfComp += 1
        while position > 0 and array[position-1] > curr:
            array[position] = array[position-1]
            position = position - 1
            numberOfSwap += 1
            if position > 0: numberOfComp += 1
        array[position] = curr
        numberOfSwap += 1

    complexityOfInsertion.append(numberOfComp)
    swapsOfInsertion.append(numberOfSwap)
    return array



def quickSort(array):
    global numberOfCompQuick
    global numberOfSwapsQuick

    less = []
    equal = []
    greater = []

    if len(array) > 1:
        pivot = array[int(len(array)/2)]

        for x in array:
            if x < pivot:
                less.append(x)
            if x == pivot:
                equal.append(x)
            if x > pivot:
                greater.append(x)
            numberOfCompQuick += 3 #can prior code to reduce this, but I'm only fixing the comp and swap counters
        numberOfSwapsQuick += 1
        # Don't forget to return something!
        return quickSort(less)+equal+quickSort(greater)  #the + operator to join lists

    else:  #when only have one element in array, just return the array.
        return array



def merge(a,b):
    """ Function to merge two arrays """
    global numberOfCompMerge
    global numberOfSwapsMerge
    c = []
    while len(a) != 0 and len(b) != 0:
        numberOfCompMerge += 1
        if a[0] < b[0]:
            c.append(a[0])
            a.remove(a[0])
        else:
            c.append(b[0])
            b.remove(b[0])
        numberOfSwapsMerge += 1
    if len(a) == 0:
        c += b
        numberOfSwapsMerge += len(b)
    else:
        numberOfSwapsMerge += len(a)
        c += a
    return c

# Code for merge sort

def mergeSort(array):
    """ Function to sort an array using merge sort algorithm """
    #global numberOfCompMerge
    if len(array) == 0 or len(array) == 1:
        return array
    else:
        middle = int(len(array)/2)
        a = mergeSort(array[:middle])
        b = mergeSort(array[middle:])
        return merge(a,b)
```

Fixed. Devil's in the details.